# Normalize mediapipe face mesh alignment

Tags: computer-vision, face-recognition, mediapipe

I want to create a face recognition pipeline.
I want to use 3d face mesh as one of the inputs to ML model.

I used mediapipe to generate 3d landmarks from a face image.
The output of mediapipe face landmarker is an array of 3d points and a 4x4 facial transformation matrix.
How can I normalize the alignment of the landmarks ?

I used 3d scatter to plot the face landmarks, they are all aligned in same way that the face in input image was aligned. But I want to have a same alignment for all generated 3d landmarks.